# Useful data flow as an API's

Tags: apache-nifi

Is their any apache Nifi API's ,where i can reuse as Data Flow as an API ...

Ex: Data Ingenstion from Local to HDFS (Data Flow), I Need to use this as Standard API ? is their any possibility in Apache nifi)

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by Standard API?  A NiFi data flow can be configured to listen to HTTP(S) requests, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Hi James,  Can you please give a sample "NiFi data flow can be configured to listen to HTTP(S) requests" ....Any document or process how to implement ......

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Hello NiFi Web Service](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/download/attachments/57904847/Hello_NiFi_Web_Service.xml?version=1&modificationDate=1449369797000&api=v2) template in the [NiFi Example Dataflow Templates](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Example+Dataflow+Templates) wiki.  The template demonstrates a simple web service that returns "Hello, NiFi!" to HTTP requests on port 8011.  You can modify it to listen to other ports and respond with your custom logic.

[image]